# How to get Latest Published version of a Lambda Function in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

How to get Latest Published version of a Lambda Function? 
Apart from `$LATEST`, how can I get the result as "5"

```
$ aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name My_Lambda_Function --query 'Versions[*][Version, FunctionArn]' --output json
[
    [
        "$LATEST",
        "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789000:function:My_Lambda_Function:$LATEST"
    ],
    [
        "1",
        "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789000:function:My_Lambda_Function:1"
    ],
    [
        "2",
        "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789000:function:My_Lambda_Function:2"
    ],
    [
        "3",
        "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789000:function:My_Lambda_Function:3"
    ],
    [
        "4",
        "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789000:function:My_Lambda_Function:4"
    ],
    [
        "5",
        "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789000:function:My_Lambda_Function:5"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 12):

I found [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4051#issuecomment-485549485) insightful, you can get the maximum non-`$LATEST` item a few ways but only one of them is correct:

**Wrong way**, this command will be correct only as far as version `9` because it will string-compare the versions and decide that `"9"` is greater than `"10"`:

```
aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name my_lambda \
  --query "max_by(Versions, &Version)"
```

**Wrong way**, this command will be correct only as far as version `50` (or whatever the page size is) because it will only filter the results that are returned in the first page.

```
aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name my_lambda \
  --query "Versions[-1]"
```

**Wrong way**, this command will consider all the results before filtering them, but still assumes that they will be in proper order

```
aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name my_lambda \
  --no-paginate \
  --query "Versions[-1]"
```

**Wrong way**, this command looks right for sorting purposes but will choke on `to_number("$LATEST")` returning `null`.

```
aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name my_lambda \
  --no-paginate \
  --query "max_by(Versions, &to_number(Version))"
```

**Wrong way**, this command looks right for sorting purposes but (on my machine) doesn't accept the literal `0`.

```
aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name my_lambda \
  --no-paginate \
  --query "max_by(Versions, &to_number(Version) || '0')"
```

**Right way**, this command will fetch all the all the results before considering them, and works around the issue of numeric literals by converting to a number twice.

```
aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name my_lambda \
  --no-paginate \
  --query "max_by(Versions, &to_number(to_number(Version) || '0'))"
```

Comment: The --no-paginate is misunderstood. From docs: "To disable pagination and return only the first page of results, use the --no-paginate option.". So "The right way" has to go without pagination. This is what is see in practice and in the docs.

Comment: Do you know how this command can be written using python and boto3?  client.list_versions_by_function(FunctionName='string')

Comment: @Matrix 
For boto3, I dislike iterating over pages using the marker, so I use:
`boto3.client('lambda').get_paginator('list_versions_by_function').paginate(FunctionName='my_lambda_name').build_full_result()`

Comment: The major issue I have with this solution is that if there are 51 versions of this lambda function, the response to this call will return info about $Latest and the versions 1 - 49. And 49 will not be the correct version that $Latest is...

Comment: Is removing `--no-paginate` the only part that needs to be changed here?

Comment: I tested this on a lambda I currently have with 177 versions.  I got the correct answer **both** *with* and *without* `--no-paginate`, so **it's not necessary**

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the version using `list-versions-by-function` and then extract second last with [jq](https://gist.github.com/olih/f7437fb6962fb3ee9fe95bda8d2c8fa4)

```
aws lambda  list-versions-by-function --function-name LogsToElasticsearch_goabode --max-items 5 \
 --query 'Versions[*].[Version,FunctionName]' | jq '.[-1]'
```

Or to get all with name

```
 aws lambda  list-versions-by-function --function-name my_lambda \
 --max-items 5 --query 'Versions[*].[Version,FunctionName]'
```

Comment: This seems to assume that `$LATEST` must always exist and that the list of all function versions will fit on one page of results.  I can't tell whether that's safe enough for scripting.

Comment: Looks like the `aws lambda list-versions-by-function` command only returns a max of 50 results, regardless of whether `--no-paginate` is specified on the command. This is something I'm running into right now. The API docs states this limitation in its description: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-versions-by-function.html - "Returns a list of versions , with the version-specific configuration of each. Lambda returns up to 50 versions per call." So as you publish more than 50 versions, turns out there's no way to get the latest actual version number.

Answer (score -1):

If your lambda is always published using a [Lambda function alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html) pointing to your latest version, then the cli query can be reduced to a single call w/o any pagination using the [get-alias](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/get-alias.html) command.

The following are placeholders; replace with your values as-needed:

- `[FunctionName]`
- `[AliasName]`
- `[AwsAccountNumber]` *(nothing to replace; just a placeholder)*

Full query:

```bash
aws lambda get-alias \
  --function-name [FunctionName] \
  --name [AliasName]
```

Result:

```json
{
    "AliasArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:[AwsAccountNumber]:function:[FunctionName]:[AliasName]",
    "Name": "[AliasName]",
    "FunctionVersion": "15",
    "Description": "Yada Yada Yada",
    "RevisionId": "7aa54e5c-1b32-4436-abcd-cf0a1aacad5a"
}
```

Reduced query to return only the version number:

```bash
aws lambda get-alias \
  --function-name [FunctionName] \
  --name [AliasName] \
  --query "to_number(FunctionVersion)"
```

Payload:

```
15
```

Comment: For me, this doesn’t work, as the “FunctionVersion” just contains “$LATEST”.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid Is your lambda published w/ a function alias?